# About EBW (Electron Beam Welding)

Tags: electrons, structural-beam

I'm an electron beam welding process engineer. We use vacuum chambers to produce close tolerance welds for the aerospace industry. The vacuum chambers are pulled down by cryogenic pumps on the newest units. Oxidized metals are a big no no in this field. The parts are mechined to very close tolerances and clamped together then placed into the vacuum chamber and pumped down before the eletron beam welding is performed. There have been occasions were we had to remove the parts from the vacuum chamber after a few hours do to mechanical issues with the electron beam but none of the parts ever fused together. 10 to the -5 or greater is the industry standard for EBW. Now I am formiluar with all types of metal welding and fusion but there is one veriable that I cannot replicate and that would be dark matter. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: My thought is that dark matter is a complete red herring. Cleaning, surface treatments, and residual gas are the big things in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dark matter is a theoretical construct intended to furnish an account of the behavior of galaxies, galaxy clusters, and superclusters. Even if it did actually exist it would have no effect on things like welding processes because it does not interact electromagnetically with ordinary matter.

Jon Custer is right, the quickest way to wreck a vacuum process is to break vacuum during a run. Adsorbed monolayers are infamous in this regard. I do not know if a pre-weld sputter etch or oxygen plasma ash/descum process step can be incorporated into your process flow but the thin film industry commonly uses one or the other to ensure interfacial adhesion- this, and not breaking vacuum between process steps.

Comment: What happened if an electron hit a dark matter?